# Response.BinaryWrite() - Getting Junk at the beginning of file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to write a string to a file that a user can download from my site.

```
var tcxString = "Some code to get my string";

byte[] bytes;
MemoryStream cvsStream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
bf.Serialize(cvsStream, tcxString);

cvsStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
bytes = cvsStream.ToArray();

Response.Clear();
Response.AppendHeader("content-length", cvsStream.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyFileName.txt");
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
```

The output becomes:

```
    ÿÿÿÿ          Some code to get my string
```

I'm guessing it has to do with my Seek location but I don't know what the correct Seek should be.  I see junk at the end of my file sometimes too.  How can I get rid of the junk at the beginning and end of my file?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? just try and write the content of your string to the output so the user can download that? Than dont use a binaryFormatter, but write the string directly to the response (your AppenHeader calls make sure that the client will treat it as a download). The junk is the product of the BinaryFormatter which serializes the string with some type/instance information appended.

Comment: Why use `BinaryWrite` instead of `WriteFile`?

Comment: polity is right.. you should not use binaryFormatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of binary formatter you are using.. try Encoding.GetBytes instead.

```
        var tcxString = "Some code to get my string";

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tcxString);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AppendHeader("content-length", bytes.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyFileName.txt");
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
```

Regards

Comment: Binary formmater is actually used to serialize object graphs, while you only need string to be converted to byte array

Answer (score 2):

Is it a text file you are writing?
Just write it's content to the output stream using Response.Write.

```
string tcxString = "Some code to get my string";

Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyFileName.txt");
Response.Write(tcxString);
```